# Laravel join and left join together in a query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a sql query i want to convert it into query builder or Laravel ORM. It works fine. But i want it into query builder form or ORM. Is it possible to write in query builder or ORM ?.

I have four tables answers, questions, users and upvote_answers. Query has three 'joins' and one 'left join' just to check current logged in user upvoted(boolean) an answer or not along with other attributes

```
   SELECT answers.answer_content as answer_content,
          answers.id as answer_id,
          answers.created_at as created_at,
          answers.created_at as answer_upvote,
          answers.created_at as answer_downvote,
          questions.id as question_id, 
          questions.question_title as question_title, 
          questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
          users.id as user_id, 
          users.name as user_name, 
          users.user_slug as user_slug,
          upvote_answers.upvote as upvote
                                        FROM 
                                            answers
                                            JOIN questions on questions.id = answers.question_id
                                            JOIN users on users.id = answers.user_id
                                            LEFT JOIN upvote_answers ON
                                                upvote_answers.answer_id = answers.id AND
                                                upvote_answers.user_id = '2'
                                        WHERE 
                                            questions.question_active = 1 and 
                                            answers.answer_active = 1
```

Comment: You can creates models for each table then create relationship between them and you don't need to join them

Comment: how , can u please tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using query builder you could write your query as

```
DB::table('answers as a')
    ->join('questions as q', 'q.id', '=', 'a.question_id')
    ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'a.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('upvote_answers as ua', function ($join) {
        $join->on('ua.answer_id', '=', 'a.id')
             ->where('ua.user_id', '=', 2);
    })
    ->where('q.question_active', '=', 1)
    ->where('a.answer_active', '=', 1)
    ->select(DB::raw('a.answer_content as answer_content,a.id as answer_id,a.created_at as created_at,a.created_at as answer_upvote,a.created_at as answer_downvote,q.id as question_id, q.question_title as question_title, q.question_slug as question_slug, u.id as user_id, u.name as user_name, u.user_slug as user_slug,ua.upvote as upvote'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but i had to write 'where' instead of 'on'. -where('ua.user_id', '=', 2);

Answer (score 0):

Use Join Clause

https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#joins

Simple example

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->where('users.id', '=', 100)
            ->get();
```

Also you can use Left Join Clause.

**Update:**

```
$yourQuery = \DB::table('answers')
    ->join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.question_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'answers.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('upvote_answers', 'upvote_answers.answer_id', '=', 'answers.id')
    ->where('questions.question_active', '=', '1')
    ->where('answers.answer_active', '=', '1')
    ->selectRaw('answers.answer_content as answer_content,
                  answers.id as answer_id,
                  answers.created_at as created_at,
                  answers.created_at as answer_upvote,
                  answers.created_at as answer_downvote,
                  questions.id as question_id, 
                  questions.question_title as question_title, 
                  questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
                  users.id as user_id, 
                  users.name as user_name, 
                  users.user_slug as user_slug,
                  upvote_answers.upvote as upvote');

echo $yourQuery->toSql(); //generated sql query as string
//$yourQuery->get(); //for get data from db
```

Result:

> select answers.answer_content as answer_content, answers.id as
>   answer_id, answers.created_at as created_at, answers.created_at as
>   answer_upvote, answers.created_at as answer_downvote, questions.id as
>   question_id, questions.question_title as question_title,
>   questions.question_slug as question_slug, users.id as user_id,
>   users.name as user_name, users.user_slug as user_slug,
>   upvote_answers.upvote as upvote from answers inner join questions on
>   questions.id = answers.question_id inner join users on users.id =
>   answers.user_id left join upvote_answers on upvote_answers.answer_id =
>   answers.id where questions.question_active = ? and
>   answers.answer_active = ?

If you need `upvote_answers.user_id = '2'` in leftJoin must use advance left join:

```
->leftJoin('upvote_answers', function($advancedLeftJoin){
    $advancedLeftJoin->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
        ->where('upvote_answers.user_id', '=', 2);
})
```

**Finally, The answer for your example is:**

```
$yourQuery = \DB::table('answers')
    ->join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.question_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'answers.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('upvote_answers', function($advancedLeftJoin){
        $advancedLeftJoin->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->where('upvote_answers.user_id', '=', 2);
    })
    ->where('questions.question_active', '=', '1')
    ->where('answers.answer_active', '=', '1')
    ->selectRaw('answers.answer_content as answer_content,
                  answers.id as answer_id,
                  answers.created_at as created_at,
                  answers.created_at as answer_upvote,
                  answers.created_at as answer_downvote,
                  questions.id as question_id, 
                  questions.question_title as question_title, 
                  questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
                  users.id as user_id, 
                  users.name as user_name, 
                  users.user_slug as user_slug,
                  upvote_answers.upvote as upvote');

echo $yourQuery->toSql(); //generated sql query as string
//dd($yourQuery->get()); //result as collection
```

Result:

> select answers.answer_content as answer_content, answers.id as
>   answer_id, answers.created_at as created_at, answers.created_at as
>   answer_upvote, answers.created_at as answer_downvote, questions.id as
>   question_id, questions.question_title as question_title,
>   questions.question_slug as question_slug, users.id as user_id,
>   users.name as user_name, users.user_slug as user_slug,
>   upvote_answers.upvote as upvote from answers inner join questions on
>   questions.id = answers.question_id inner join users on users.id =
>   answers.user_id left join upvote_answers on users.id =
>   contacts.user_id and upvote_answers.user_id = ? where
>   questions.question_active = ? and answers.answer_active = ?

`?` value bind after use `->get()`

Comment: My query is different from your query.